# Formatting in SAS to Create Buckets

Tags: sas, format

I use the following code to bucket my continuous variable in SAS, but it does not work:

```
proc freq data = right;
  table Age;
run; 

proc format;
value AgeBuckets  
  low -<  74 = "Younger"
  75 -< 84 = "Older"
  85 - high = "Oldest"
run;

data right;
  format Age AgeBuckets.;
run;
```

It removes all of the records so I have no more data in there. What am I doing wrong?

Also, would it perhaps be best to simply create a new variable (bucketed version) off of the continuous one with if/then statements?

Comment: This is really where comments help, because we don't always know what you're trying to do. And no, using IF/THEN statements is never more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You are just not setting the dataset - rather creating a new one.

```
data right;
  set right;
  format Age AgeBuckets.;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Also you are excluding ages 74 and 84 from the buckets. You may want to include them also:

```
proc format;
value AgeBuckets  
  low -<  74 = "Younger"
  74 -< 84 = "Older"
  84 - high = "Oldest"
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is your exact code, you're missing a semicolon after the last element in your PROC FORMAT statement.  That would likely cause the issue you've described.  It should read

```
proc format;
value AgeBuckets  
  low -<  74 = "Younger"
  75 -< 84 = "Older"
  85 - high = "Oldest";
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You made a mistake in your data step, where you didn't reference the input file since you have no SET statement.
2. It's rarely more efficient to use IF/THEN statements
3. If you want a new variable use PUT to convert it, illustrated here
4. Programming where you use the same name for the input and output data set is a bad idea, it makes it very hard to find your mistakes.

   ```
   proc format;
   value AgeBuckets  
     low  -< 75 = "Younger"
     75 -< 85 = "Older"
     85 - high = "Oldest"
   run;

   data right_formatted;
     set right;
     format Age AgeBuckets.;
     *create new variable with formatted value, will not sort correctly;
     Age_Formatted = put(age, ageBuckets.);
   run;
   ```

and:

```
   *applying a format means that it sorts correctly for display;
   proc freq data=right_formatted;
   table age age_formatted ;
   format age ageBuckets.;
   run;
```

@Python R SAS user is correct about your formats as well.

Comment: put is great! It changed both the new age_formatted variable as well as the "original" age variable. May I somehow use put so that the original age distribution stays intact next to the new formatted version? So the original age distribution of (let's say) 50 levels is the first column and the column next to it has 3 levels (not counting missing).

One more question - in using put I would be very interested in if it bucketed the age levels into something numeric like 1, 2, 3 instead of the text. Is there an easy or recommended way to do this?

Comment: The `format` statement changes the display of the original variable. `put` recodes it into a new variable, similar to IF/THEN. To change the display or values seen, change the format. You really need to understand each step here, as it's some of the basics of working with data in SAS. So change different things and see what happens so you understand what every line is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrote the dataset with the extra data step.  But why did you want the data step at all?  Just add the FORMAT statement to procedure that wants to group the values by their formatted values.

```
proc freq data = right;
  table Age;
  format Age AgeBuckets.;
run;
```